# Update Node Version in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Does anyone know of a sanctioned way to update Node within Visual Studio 2017? I've got Node 6 set up on my development PC but VS2017 appears to come with a bundled copy of Node 5, which means that running `npm install` on my command line sets up various packages like `node-sass` with bindings for Node 6, so when I then run gulp tasks from the VS Task Runner things fall over due to the mismatched versions.

I found the VS Node install at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External` but I'm a little reluctant to just hack about and replace it. Anyone got any experience of upgrading this? I know I can sync by downgrading the version on my PC but that seems backwards.

Comment: Top Google result for 'visual studio node version' seems like it might do the trick: https://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: @JoeClay that's for VS2015, things have changed in VS2017. I already tried Google...

Comment: Ah, I just opened VS, the option has moved...

Comment: This https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1686 is also related which means nodejs location must be present in System's Path variable.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Go to:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools

Then you need to add your Node install directory to the top of the list, like so:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not sure what this does, as it hasn't updated anything.

Comment: As an alternative that worked for me, just bump the $(PATH) up one, so it supercedes the Web\External directory (assuming node is installed on your environment path)

Comment: Mine worked by doing what the answer states. However, this is the second time this issue happened, the first time it was resolved using @Leniency's comment. :)

Comment: "supercedes" or maybe "precedes"

Comment: @Leniency this worked a treat for me - a node extension (NPM Task Runner by Mads) was using a different (VS) version of node and was failing - thanks!

Answer (score 67):

You don't need to add a new Node install directory, Node exists in PATH.
Notice how **$(PATH)** is below the internal path **$(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External**.

To use the global PATH environment variable before the internal path, you can just use the arrows at the top-right to change the order.

This is what it looks like when the global PATH is searched before the internal one and therefore will make Visual Studio use your own versions of the tools.
[image]

Comment: This worked for me.  Some package ended up being before '$(PATH)', but when I moved '$(PATH)' up underneath '.\node_modules\.bin' gulp started working again and I got my web app icons back :)

Comment: Instead of that, you may also see `${VSInstalledExternalTools}`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue turned out to be that there was a local `node.exe` file in the same directory that the `csproj` file was in, along with a `node.exe.config` file.

I had a post-build event that would call `gulp` to do some other work and VS2017 would use the local `node.exe` file rather than what was listed in my `$(PATH)` variable. This was an earlier version of node that I didn't want to use, so the solution for me was to either remove the local `node.exe` so the one listed in `$(PATH)` would be used or upgrade the local `node.exe` file if the `node.exe.config` is really needed.

I just wanted to add this here in case someone else runs into this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if options in

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools

have no effect. However it is possible to set the Node version through

> Project > Properties

[image: Project>properties screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 version, you must set Node install directory in environment variable PATH, when you create a project throught Visual Studio Project template System in Visual Studio 2022 version. Unless Visual Studio 2022 can't find npm and npx.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).